# C++ const lost on reference

Tags: c++

Why does this compile?

```
struct A {};
struct B {
    B(A& _a) : a(_a) {}
    A   &a;
};

void f1(A&) {}
void f2(const B &b) { f1(b.a); }

int main() {
    A a;
    B b{a};
    f2(b);
    return 0;
}
```

Inside f2() b is const, so my understanding was that b.a should also be const. But it does compile and the compiler allows calling f1().

Replace 'A& a;' in struct B with 'A a;' and it no longer works.
Now in f1() b.a indeed is const:

```
invalid initialization of reference of type 'A&' from expression of type 'const A'
```

Please help me understand this... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an object is `const`, it doesn't cause the reference members to also become `const` since the referent is not a part of the object itself. The reference member is just a piece of information representing the address of some other object. Whether or not the `B` object itself is immutable shouldn't affect whether it should be possible to mutate the objects it references.

If you make the `B::a` member a non-reference, as in `A a;`, then the `B` object will actually contain within itself an `A` object, so when the former is `const`, the latter will be too.

Answer (score 1):

> Inside f2() b is const, so my understanding was that b.a should also be const.

It is. If the instance is `const` then it's members will be, too. But look at the type of the member:

```
A & a;
```

That's a reference to `A`. Making that `const` yields a constant reference to `A`:

```
A & const a;
```

*Not* a reference to a constant `A`.

Comment: error: 'const' qualifiers cannot be applied to 'A&'

Comment: Who says that? (In what context?) Yes, it is [completely redundant](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-nonsense). Anyway, it was more meant as thought experiment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking there are no constant references. There are references to constant objects.

In the class B the data member `a`  is declared like a reference to non-constant object of the type A.

```
A   &a;
```

and this reference is passed as an argument to a function that accepts a reference to a non-constant object

```
void f1(A&) {}
void f2(const B &b) { f1(b.a); }
```

Thus the code compiles successfully.